# Matlab morphological operation - thin vs. skel?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, binary-image

I'm wondering if someone can explain the difference between these two Matlab algorithms, `bwmorph(binary_image,'thin',N_iterations)` and `bwmorph(binary_image,'skel',N_iterations)`. For my application, they produce results that are typically slightly different from each other, and I am trying to figure out the difference. Thanks!

Comment: What happens for very big number of iteration?

Comment: https://se.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html describes the `thin` version whereas the `skel` uses single applylut at each iteration. So I guess the added complexity would be there to improve the result, e.g. lesser scanline order dependency, more central, less noisy skeleton etc.